# Is taking the inf valid in this situation?

Tags: real-analysis

All the functions in this question are real valued. I'm not sure if the following is valid and It would be appreciated if someone could verify it.

Let $G$ be a real number, $g:C_n\to\mathbb{R}$ for a given domain $C_n\subset \mathbb{R}$ depending on $n$ and $K:A\to\mathbb{R}$ is an operator, which takes a real valued continuous function and maps it to the reals. Assume we find for every $g$ as above $f_g\in A$ depending on $g$ such that

$$G\le K(f_g) + \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}$$

We define $L(g):=\inf\{K(f_g):f_g\in A\}$. Is the following valid: Suppose this $g$ and an $\epsilon >0$ is fixed. Then, is the following valid: I choose a $f_g\in A$ such that $L(g)+\epsilon \ge K(f_g)$ using the definition of the infimum s.t.

$$G\le K(f_g)+\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}\le L(g) +\epsilon +\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}\tag{1}$$

Now I would like to take the infimum over $L(g)$, i.e.

$$G\le \inf\{L(g)|g:C_n\to\mathbb{R}\}+\epsilon +\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}$$

Is this true? I know that for a fixed $\epsilon$ and for every $g$ I can find a $f_g\in A$ such that $(1)$ is true. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is the map $\{g\} \rightarrow A, \ \ g \mapsto f_g$ surjective?  Does $n$ index $g$ or vise versa?

Comment: It seems like $L(g)$ has one element in its infimum or are there many $f_g \in A$ for each $g$?

Comment: @EnjoysMath Thanks for your answer. the map $g\mapsto f_g$ needs not to be surjective. Yes $n$ index $g$. What you know is, that for every such $g$ there is at least one $f_g\in A$. What you actually have: For fixed $n$ and $\epsilon$ you know that for every such $g$ there is at least one $f_g$ such that $G\le L(g)+\epsilon +\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}$. And  the question is, can I replace $L(g)$ with the infimum over all these $L(g)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(1)\ $ $\sqrt{n}/n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and it shrinks as $n$ grows, so the min of the bound $G -n/\sqrt{n}$ is $G-1$.  So $\{K(f_g)\}$ is a set of reals bounded below, so it has an infimum in $\mathbb{R}$.

$(2)\ $ By definition of infimum there exists $K(f_g)$ values less than $L(g) + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon \gt 0$.  So yes, you can choose such a fixed $\epsilon$ and find an $f_g$ with those requirements.

$(3)\ $ This is unfortunately not valid, at least knowing nothing else but $(1)$.  Since we choose $f_{g_0}$ and thus $g_0, n_0, \epsilon_0$, then what I understand that you have is
$$
G \ \leq \ K(f_{g_0}) + \sqrt{n_0}/n_0 \ \leq \ L(g_0) + \epsilon_0 + \sqrt{n_0}/n_0
$$
and you want to replace $L(g_0)$ in the above with the general infimum over the $L(g)$.  But there could be $g$ that violate that inequality.

Comment: Have you seen my comment above? So you think it is still not valid?